# When to declare methods as private

Tags: oop, design-patterns, coding-style

I am looking for specific and exact rules to determine how a method's visibility can be declared. This is not language agnostic, it applies to the standard OOP languages.

Comment: You rather mean it *is* language agnostic, but not language specific.

Answer (score 4):

A good rule to follow would be:

> Members should not have more accessibility than they need.

Start with `private` and make them more accessible as the need arises.

Comment: +1, But from where are you quoting this? I'd be curious to see the context, and the rest of the article.

Comment: I just made it up but I'm certain it has been said before

Comment: Yes but the members may already be defined incorrectly in terms of OOP (eg: one giant class handling multiple concerns).

Comment: @hunter I should have phrased my question with concern on how to create the API/design first and not how to apply private/public to existing methods.

Answer (score 1):

Basically:

- Public is for when the method must be accessible by an outside class. Something like `getState()` would fit here.
- Private is for when the method should not be accessible by any other class, something like `changeState(...)`. Generally this relates to the actual alteration of an object's contents - maybe you'll have a public `setX(int x)` that just calls the private `setXInternal(int x)`, that way you can have extra type-checking/safety/etc. To be safe you might as well make everything private until it has to be otherwise.
- Protected is basically "public to child classes, private otherwise". Could go either way.

Answer (score 1):

With any class/object there are:
1. things it does (behaviours)
2. how it does them (implementation)

The world cares about the behaviour of your object. It shouldn't (often) care about how it achieves this behaviour under the hood. Keep implementation details private, and expose behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of operation which does not define behaviour of particular object directly but is useful during implementation of object's behaviour is a candidate for private member function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the helpfulness of the public, protected and private keywords is just to make the code more clear.

So you would use public for the API of a class, private to make it clear how to do NOT extend a class and protected in every other case.

A common pragmatic approach is never use private and to use just public or protected.

Answer (score 0):

Public for things that are part of the public API.
Protected for non-public functions that you want subclasses to be able to call.
Private if you don't want subclasses mucking around with said method (or to even know of its existence).

In C, C++, and C# don't forgot to mark a method virtual if you want a child class to be able to override it.